# Multiply by a range's assigned value

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to simply multiply two ranges by one another, and it is activated by a activeX button, but it keeps giving me the #Name? error obv from the multiplication error but i do not know how to edit that correctly.
Thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rngData     As Range
    Dim rngNum     As Range

    Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Custom Systems").Range("G16")
      Set rngNum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Custom Systems").Range("c8")
    rngData = Evaluate(rngData.Address & "* rngNum")
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking; Are you looking to multiply two cells to get the value? What are you trying to accomplish with `rngData = Evaluate(rngData.Address & "* rngNum")`?

Comment: `rngData = Evaluate(rngData.Address & "*" & rngNum.Address)` but @YowE3k answer is a better method.

Comment: @ScottCraner - VBA is weird!  It appears that your suggestion works, but only if you add `.Value`, i.e. `rngData.Value = Evaluate(rngData.Add‌​ress & "*" & rngNum.Address)`.

Comment: @YowE3K it is necessary if the range is more than one cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I tried it on a single cell as well, and it still didn't work.  (It doesn't crash - but it just doesn't update the value.)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution to your question would be:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Custom Systems")
    .Range("G16").Value = .Range("G16").Value * .Range("c8").Value
End With
```

or

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Custom Systems")
    Set RngData = .Range("G16")
    Set RngNum = .Range("c8")
    RngData.Value = RngData.Value * RngNum.Value
End With
```

(`.Value` is the default property, so that can be omitted if you want to save some characters while typing.)

---

If the `RngData` range is not a single cell, the above method won't work.  In that situation I would iterate over each cell, e.g.

```
Dim oneCell As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngdata = .Range("G11:G27")
    Set rngnum = .Range("C6")

    For Each oneCell In rngdata
        oneCell.Value = oneCell.Value * rngnum.Value
    Next

End With
```

Alternatively, you could fall back to using the built-in Paste Special Values Multiply method, e.g.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngdata = .Range("G11:G27")
    Set rngnum = .Range("C6")

    rngnum.Copy
    rngdata.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                         Operation:=xlMultiply

End With
```

Or you could use the `Evaluate` function in that situation:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngdata = .Range("G11:G27")
    Set rngnum = .Range("C6")

    'Note: The ".Value" is required in the next line or it will not work
    rngdata.Value = Evaluate(rngdata.Address & "*" & rngNum.Address)
End With
```

Personally, I don't like the `Evaluate` method - I suspect it would be more inefficient than other methods.

Comment: using the code it keeps resulting in a mismatch error

Comment: Private Sub Calc_Click()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Custom Systems")
    Set rngData = .Range("G11:G27")
    Set rngNum = .Range("C6")
    rngData.Value = rngData.Value * rngNum.Value
End With
End Sub

Comment: @M.Puglia - I have updated the answer to cater for multiple cells in `rngData`.

Comment: Evaluate is faster than looping on large datasets, but the pastespecial is faster than evaluate.

Comment: @Scott Craner for me `PasteSpecial` was few times slower when I tested it with those two answers (but maybe because of the `.SpecialCells` part) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930863/multiply-each-value-in-a-range-by-a-constant-but-skip-blank-cells/38934067#38934067

Comment: I'm learning more from this one question than I have probably learned in the last year!

Answer (score 2):

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Custom Systems")
    .[G11:G27] = .[G11:G27*C6]
End With
```

Comment: Cool!  I assume the `[G11:G27*C6]` is just implicitly doing an Evaluate.

Comment: @YowE3K Yes, it's short for something like `.Range("G11:G27") = .Evaluate("G11:G27*C6")` (note the dot in front). I can't test it, but if you have time you can test how fast it is with `Timer`. I suspect it to be faster than the other alternatives. The overhead from `Evaluate` is indeed slow, but the calculation is fast.