# Whole Column as text

Tags: vba

I have an excel document which the first column is formated:

```
date
2017-08-01
2017-08-01
2017-08-01
2017-08-01
2017-08-01
```

What I do is to copy the whole column to a text document and paste it back to the worksheet. Tt fixes the date format on its own, it comes back, perfectly:

```
DATE
01/08/2017
01/08/2017
01/08/2017
01/08/2017
01/08/2017
```

I have tried formating the cells within excel (dd/mm/yyyy) and record macro, nothing works, only the cutting and pasting onto notepad, now I need to achieve this by vba, I tried the normal:

```
     Range("a2:a5").Select
 Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
```

But it did not work, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `Range("A2:A5").NumberFormat="dd/mm/yyyy"` (note - no need to use Select, just format the range).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the [`Evaluate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel) methods for convertiong texts to number:

```
[a2:a6] = [--a2:a6]
[a2:a6].NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

there is also the Excel method of copying blank cell and selecting `Add` in the `Paste Special` dialog:

```
[b1].Copy                                           ' copy blank cell
[a2:a6].PasteSpecial , xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd   ' and add it to the destination range
[a2:a6].NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the dates are stored as text you can multiply them by 1 (or add 0) and then format.  The calculation on the range lets Excel know it's dealing with numbers.

The code was taken from  [Multiply Entire Range By Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990541/multiply-entire-range-by-value)

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rData As Range

    Set rData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A5")
    rData = Evaluate(rData.Address & "*1")
    rData.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

End Sub
```